# What is NSdocumentdirectory's limitation size?

Tags: ios, iphone, nsdocumentdirectory

What is the `maximum size` of `NSDocumentdirectory` that can be `stored`?.

Mostly I am `saving` `images` in `NSDocumentdirectory`, as it is `backed` up by `iCloud`.

Now i would like to `know` what is the maximum size that can be stored in it. Please help.

Answer (score -1):

This code is giving  the exact number of bytes.

```
- (unsigned long long int)folderSize:(NSString *)folderPath {
    NSArray *folderArray = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] subpathsOfDirectoryAtPath:folderPath error:nil];
    NSEnumerator *folderEnumerator = [folderArray objectEnumerator];
     NSString *folderName;
     unsigned long long int fileSize = 0;

     while (folderName = [folderEnumerator nextObject]) {
      NSDictionary *folderDictionary = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileAttributesAtPath:[folderPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:fileName] traverseLink:YES];
    folderSize += [folderDictionary folderSize];
}

   return folderSize;
}
```

Hope it helps...

Comment: The OP wants to know the limit, not the current usage.

Comment: Yes I would like to know the maximum limit not the size.